# To solve $8z^6+1=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

So there is an equation
$$8z^6+1=0$$
Apparently
$$z^6=-\frac18$$
But how to proceed with the stuff? I know that I have to describe $z$ as $e^{ik\theta}$, but have actually no idea which angle should stand there.

Comment: You can also recognize that the first line is a sum of cubes. Factoring it down is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. When you multiply complex numbers you add their angles. Where should you put a complex number so that six times its angle brings it to the negative real axis (angle $\pi$)?

Comment: Six times the angle should be $\pi$, not $0$.

Comment: @GregordeCillia Right you are thanks. Fixed the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ then
$$z^6=|z|^6e^{i6\theta}=\frac{e^{i\pi}}{8}=-\frac{1}{8}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad |z|=\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{8}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\quad\mbox{and}\quad 6\theta =\pi+2k\pi, \;\mbox{with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.}$$
What are the six solutions of the equation?

Answer (score 1):

Write $z=re^{ik}$ (although we'd usually use $\theta$ in place of $k$) with $r>0$. Then $\frac{1}{8}e^{\pi i} =-\frac{1}{8}=z^6=r^6 e^{6ki}$. The easy part is finding $r$. Equating moduli, $r^6=\frac{1}{8}$ so $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

The hard part is finding $k$. It's not as simple as equating complex exponents to write $k=\frac{\pi}{6}$, because $e^{\pi i}$ can be more generally written as $e^{\left( 1+2n\right)\pi i}$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $k=\frac{\pi}{6}+n\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Since $n\to n+6$ preserves $e^{k i}$, to find all possible values of $re^{ki}$ we need only consider the cases $0\le n\le 5$. If $n=0$ we get $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\pi i/6}=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}$. I'll leave the other cases to you.